# How to get the count in number of days bucket in MySql or R

Tags: mysql, r, dataframe, dplyr

I am using two tables which like:

T1

```
ID       Name       Insertion_Date

TT-1     ABC        2019-09-22 14:22:18
TT-2     XYZ        2019-08-28 15:12:11
```

T2

```
id       Date            value            type   id_2
TT-1     2019-09-03      10,100           A      1001
TT-1     2019-07-12      10,100           A      1002
TT-1     2018-04-18      50,000           A      1003
TT-1     2019-04-03      55,000           B      1004
TT-2     2019-09-01      11,500           A      1005
TT-2     2019-05-22      12,100           B      1006
TT-2     2018-08-30      12,000           B      1007
TT-2     2017-06-12      15,000           C      1008
```

I am trying to joining both the tables and try to get the below mentioned output, using MySQL.

Where, the variable `6month` contains the count of entries are there of `ID` TT-1 between `Insertion_Date` to 180 days or six month, same goes for `12month` and `>12month`.

The `Total` column contains the total number of `ID` in the T2.

Output:

```
ID       Name        6month     12month      >12month   Total
TT-1     ABC           3           0             1        4
TT-2     XYZ           2           0             2        4
```

Sample Dataframe:

```
id       Date            value            type   id_2    Insertion_Date
TT-1     2019-09-03      10,100           A      1001    2019-09-22 14:22:18
TT-1     2019-07-12      10,100           A      1002    2019-09-22 14:22:18
TT-1     2018-04-18      50,000           A      1003    2019-09-22 14:22:18
TT-1     2019-04-03      55,000           B      1004    2019-09-22 14:22:18
TT-2     2019-09-01      11,500           A      1005    2019-08-28 15:12:11
TT-2     2019-05-22      12,100           B      1006    2019-08-28 15:12:11
TT-2     2018-08-30      12,000           B      1007    2019-08-28 15:12:11
TT-2     2017-06-12      15,000           C      1008    2019-08-28 15:12:11
```

Comment: Try searching for mysql pivot and mysql conditional aggregation (I assume you know how to join 2 tables)

Comment: @P.Salmon: Yes, I know how to join two table and tried to pivot the table with case when condition, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please add your code attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do aggregation based on some conditions in the select statement too.

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID, 
    t1.Name, 
    SUM(IF(t2.Date > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 MONTH AND t2.Date <= CURRENT_DATE, 1 , 0)) AS '6Month',
    SUM(IF(t2.Date > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND t2.Date <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 MONTH, 1 , 0)) AS '12Month',
    SUM(IF(t2.Date <= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 12 MONTH , 1 , 0)) AS '>12month',
    COUNT(0) AS Total
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t1.ID
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.Name;
```

Comment: Is it generating some error? can you share error or  any discrepancies that you are facing?